# How to invoke async.map function with an iterator with multiple arguments?

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous, node-async

I have this function:

```
_get(url, param, function(err, body, res) {
  /* do something */
});
```

**I need to execute this function several times where `param` takes different values each iteration.** (`param` comes from an array)

So, I decided to try with `async.map` as stated on the documentation has this definition:

> map(arr, iterator, [callback])

Where `iterator` needs to be something like `iterator(item, callback)`
So, at this moment I see that my function it's not compatible, so for that matter I tried to resolve like this

```
var fn = function(param, callback) {
  return _get(url, param, callback);
};
```

And when I executed with `async.map` I expected to get the merged results like this

```
async.map(scope, fn, function(err, results) {
  /* handle results */
});
```

But `results` returns `undefined`. I suspect because the `return` inside `fn` which misleads `async.map`.

What should I change/correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `return` won't have any effect on `async.map`. I think the problem is with the signature of the callback.
Assuming `scope` is the array where you have your `param` values, the following should run your function over those values and provide an array in `results` - assuming `_get` calls its anonymous callback with no error:

```
async.map(scope, function(param, cb) {

   _get(url, param, function(err, body, res) {
       if (err) return cb(err);
       /* do something */
       cb(null, /* whatever you want to pass on to final callback */);
   })
},
function(err, result) {
   if (err) // handle err

   // result is array of values from _get's callback
})
```